# How to inspect IndexedDB data for chrome extension manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

For chrome extension manifest v2, I can open the background page in DevTools, open the "Application" tab, select "IndexedDB", and I see the data. This approach doesn't work for service worker (manifest v3). The data is not displayed. I'm sure the data is present, but not displayed.

How to inspect IndexedDB data for chrome extension manifest v3?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that devtools for a service worker doesn't show storage.

The solution is to open a visible page of your extension like the popup or options, then open devtools for that page (right-click it, then inspect).

In case your extension doesn't have a page, you can open `chrome-extension://ID/manifest.json` where `ID` is the ID of your extension shown in chrome://extensions page.